# What is known about this group reminiscent of the anharmonic group?

Tags: finite-groups, rational-functions

The **anharmonic group** is this nonabelian group of six rational functions with the operation of composition of functions:
\begin{align}
t & \mapsto t & & \text{order 1} \\[8pt]
t & \mapsto 1/t & & \text{order 2} \\
t & \mapsto 1-t & & \text{order 2} \\
t & \mapsto t/(t-1) & & \text{order 2} \\[8pt]
t & \mapsto 1/(1-t) & & \text{order 3} \\
t & \mapsto (t-1)/t & & \text{order 3}
\end{align}
The reason it is called "anharmonic" appears to be that a set of four numbers is said to divide the line harmonically if their cross-ratio is $1$, and so the cross-ratio measures deviation from harmonic division, and when four numbers with cross-ratio $t$ are permuted, this group gives the six values that the cross-ratio can take.  The members of this group permute the elements $0$, $1$, and $\infty$ of $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$.

Today I noticed that something very similar-looking forms a group of four elements, each of the three non-identity elements having order $2$:
\begin{align}
t & \mapsto t \\
t & \mapsto -1/t \\
t & \mapsto (1-t)/(1+t) \\
t & \mapsto (t+1)/(t-1)
\end{align}

- Can anything interesting be said about this, including, but not limited to, relevance to geometry, algebra, combinatorics, probability, number theory, physics, or engineering?
- What other finite groups of rational functions as simple as these exist?

Comment: The classification of finite groups of Mobius transformations is known and classical. They are classified by Dynkin diagrams. Look up "finite subgroups of SU(2)" and "McKay correspondence."

Comment: It seems that it's known that all finite subgroups of $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb R)$ are cyclic or dihedral.  Depending on what you mean by "as simple as these", you might glean some information from this paper: http://home.wlu.edu/~dresdeng/papers/nine.pdf.  The largest group with nice integer coefficients is $D_6$.

Comment: @ErickWong : Maybe you should make your comment an answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : Maybe you should make your comment an answer. $\qquad$

Comment: I will add a link to the previous question about the group of six functions: [Name and role of a particular finite group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1351753)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group of invertible rational functions, which explicitly consists of Mobius transformations $z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$, is abstractly the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Its finite subgroups are known: by an averaging argument they correspond to finite subgroups of $PSU(2) \cong SO(3)$, the group of orientation-preserving isometries of the sphere $S^2$. There are two infinite sequences of such subgroups, the cyclic groups $C_n$ and the dihedral groups $D_n$, and then three "exceptional" groups given by the symmetry groups of the Platonic solids:

- $A_4$, the symmetry group of the tetrahedron.
- $S_4$, the symmetry group of the cube and the octahedron.
- $A_5$, the symmetry group of the icosahedron and dodecahedron.

The subgroups you've identified are two copies of the dihedral subgroups $D_3$ and $D_2$ respectively. There are many copies of the cyclic and dihedral groups, each corresponding to rotations about a different axis.

For more on this the keyword is the [McKay correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKay_graph). These finite groups also show up in Galois theory because each of these finite groups $G$ acts on $\mathbb{C}(t)$ by automorphisms, and so we get $\mathbb{C}(t)$ as a Galois extension of $\mathbb{C}(t)^G$ with Galois group $G$.