# Common patterns among functions obtained by composition

Tags: functions

Consider the function $F(x)=1- 1/x$
And also look at the process given below. After doing it all we just get the inverse of the function. Is this some form of pattern here and also why?
[the process involving function F(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KJ0o.jpg)

$$f(x)=1-\frac1x$$

$$f(\tfrac1x)=1-x$$

$$f(f(\tfrac1x))=1-\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{x}{x-1}$$

**Edit**:- **Please also consider my background before answering or commenting. I hold no degree and am in my high school final year.**

Comment: See [Mobius Transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DietrichBurde can I use Mathjax for mobile.

Comment: Could you give some description about this?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order to stick to the content of the question. Do you agree ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sure Sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your functions belong to the following set :

$$\begin{cases}\Phi_1(x)=x, & \Phi_2(x)=1-\tfrac{1}{x},&\Phi_3(x)=\tfrac{1}{1-x},\\
\Phi_4(x)=1-x, & \Phi_5(x)=\tfrac{1}{x},
  & \Phi_6(x)=\tfrac{x}{x-1}\end{cases}$$

of 6 functions which is "closed" for composition, and moreover has a group structure for this operation of composition (see remark 1 at the bottom of this answer). A detailed explanation can be found in an old answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2265961/305862).

Let us take it from the beginning.

Have you noticed that all the operations you are doing deal with so-called homographic functions (sometimes called Möbius functions) having the form

$$\varphi(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} $$

for certain coefficients $a,b,c,d$. For example,

- if $a=1, b=-1, c=1, d=0,$ one gets function $f(x)=1-\frac1x=\frac{x-1}{x} ;$
- if $a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0,$ one gets function $g(x)=\frac1x$ ;
- if $a=-1, b=1, c=0, d=1,$ one gets (affine) function $h(x)=1-x=\frac{-x+1}{0x+1}$, which can be considered as a homographic function, etc.

The main point is that when two homographic functions $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ and $g(x)=\frac{a'x+b'}{c'x+d'}$ are composed in the following way $g \circ f(x)=g(f(x))$, you find back a homographic function.

Proof :

$$g(f(x))=\frac{a'f(x)+b'}{c'f(x)+d'}=\frac{a'\tfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}+b'}{c'\tfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}+d'}=$$

$$=\frac{a'(ax+b)+b'(cx+d)}{c'(ax+b)+d'(cx+d)}=$$

$$=\frac{(a'a+b'c)x+(a'b+b'd)}{(c'a+d'c)x+(c'd+d'd)}$$

One often prefers to reason on square arrays called matrices (maybe you haven't seen them yet) under the form :

$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{a'&b'\\c'&d'}}_{\text{coeff. of } g} \underbrace{\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}}_{\text{coeff. of } f} = \underbrace{\pmatrix{(a'a+b'c)&(a'b+b'd)\\(c'a+d'c)&(c'd+d'd)}}_{\text{coeff. of } g \circ f}$$

For example, your calculation $f(1/x)=-x+1$ corresponds to the following matrix product :

$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&0}}_{\text{coeff. of } f}\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}}_{\text{coeff. of } 1/x}=\underbrace{\pmatrix{\color{red}{-1}&\color{red}{1}\\\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{1}}}_{\text{coeff. of} -x+1} $$

i.e., with notations above :

$$\Phi_2 \circ \Phi_5 = \Phi_4 $$

The set of homographic functions is infinite, whereas the group you use is finite (as said at the beginning of this answer).

**Remarks :**

1. If you have already met the notion of "group" in mathematics, here are some precision about the so-called "anharmonic group" of 6 functions ; its "Cayley table" for the composition operation is as follows :

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\circ & \Phi_1 & \Phi_2  & \Phi_3 & \Phi_4 & \Phi_5 & \Phi_6 \\
\hline
\Phi_1 & \Phi_1 & \Phi_2 & \Phi_3 & \Phi_4 & \Phi_5 & \Phi_6\\
\Phi_2 & \Phi_2 & \Phi_3 & \Phi_1 & \Phi_6 & \Phi_4 & \Phi_5\\
\Phi_3 & \Phi_3 & \Phi_1 & \Phi_2 & \Phi_5 & \Phi_6 & \Phi_4\\
\Phi_4 & \Phi_4 & \Phi_5 & \Phi_6 & \Phi_1 & \Phi_2 & \Phi_3\\
\Phi_5 & \Phi_5 & \Phi_6 & \Phi_4 & \Phi_3 & \Phi_1 & \Phi_2\\
\Phi_6 & \Phi_6 & \Phi_4 & \Phi_5 & \Phi_2 & \Phi_3 & \Phi_1 \end{array}$$

Do you retrieve relationship $\Phi_2 \circ \Phi_5 = \Phi_4 $ ? (which is different from $\Phi_5 \circ \Phi_2 = \Phi_6$ : the group isn't commutative). Please note also that function $\Phi_1$ defined by $\Phi_1(x)=x$ is neutral for function's composition which is quite logical...

You can notice in particular that the three first functions constitute a stable subset (in fact a particular subgroup).

The main group is isomorphic to $S_3$, the group of the $3!=6$ permutations on 3 elements ; the subgroup $\{\Phi_1,\Phi_2,\Phi_3\}$, which is the subgroup of matrices having $\det=1$, is isomorphic to the so-called alternating group $A_3$.

2. A homographic function is defined by its four coefficients **up to a multiplicative factor** : $(ka,kb,kc,kd)$ gives the same function as $(a,b,c,d)$ due to simplication by $k$. This property is called, for reasons that we will not give here, a "projective property".
3. Now, in case you have already studied complex numbers, here is a completely different view on functions $\Phi_k$ when they are considered no longer as functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but as functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Let us start from a value of $z$ belonging to the so-called fundamental domain $D_1$ in red. If we apply to it function $\Phi_2$ defined by $\Phi_2(z)=1-\tfrac{1}{z}$, one will obtain a point in the yellow region. If, instead, we apply to it function $\Phi_4(z)=1-z$, you will obtain a point in region $D_4$ etc. In this way, all the plane is covered.

(The figure has been created by taking $5000$ random points in the red area, then computing their images by the different $\Phi_k$.)

[image]

Comment: Is it clearer now ? Don't hesitate to ask some more information (begining by @Jean Marie) Congratulations for being interested in this kind of mathematics at an early age.

Comment: I have added a new figure and new explanations.

Comment: Interesting things also [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693670/305862)

Comment: can x take the value of iota also?

Comment: If, by "iota", you mean the "i" of complex numbers ($i^2=-1$), the answer is : yes.