# Is there any mathematical interest in functions $f(x)$ such that $f^{\circ3}(x) = x$?

Tags: functions

It should at least be mildly amusing that such functions exist.  For example the functions $1/x$ and $1 - x$ are both self-inverse, $f^{\circ2}(x)=x$.  Now let's do a mix and match on these two functions to get $g(x)= 1-1/x$ and $h(x) = 1/(1-x)$. Neither of these functions is self-inverse, but $g^{\circ3}(x) = h^{\circ3}(x) = x$. Further, $g^{\circ2} = h$ and $h^{\circ2} = g$.

Comment: See, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659401/are-there-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-of-arbitrary-group-theoretic-order) for example.

Comment: These are sometimes referred to as "*cyclical functions (of order 3).*"  [See here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1874h1013752) for such a usage. 
 Certainly the concept is well studied in the context of algebra and permutations, but I personally don't usually encounter much interest in it outside of those settings.  (*Of course, that may say more about me than about the problem*).

Comment: [Several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) [very](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations) [relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Group_of_nth_roots_of_unity).

Comment: A very recent question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4682198/305862).